# How to use second button while first button is active

Tags: php, jquery, html

This is code i have, when i press button get first choice, i get to select second value, but when i try to select second value i get back to the first selection. I need that structure to remain the same, just i need that everytime i press second button it would not refresh the page, just defines second value, for example when i choose color Red i could make echo say red bird, red lizard red dragon just by pressing second button, but after i select first to green, then page refreshes and again then i can choose green animal when ever second button is pressed. I can't even see if echo works because everytime i press second button i go back where i start.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="output" action = "" method="POST">
        <select name="Color">
            <option value="Red">Red</option>
            <option value="Green">Green</option>
            <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option value="Pink">Pink</option>
            <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="get first choice" />
        <br>

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
            $selected_val = $_POST['Color'];  
            echo "You have selected :" .$selected_val; 
        }
        ?>

        <br>
        <select name="Animal">
            <option value="Bird">Bird</option>
            <option value="Lizard">Lizard</option>
            <option value="Dragon">Dragon</option>
            <option value="Dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="Fish">Fish</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="get second choice" />

        <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
            $selected_val2 = $_POST['Animal'];
            echo "Your combination is :" .$selected_val ." " .$selected_val2;  
        }
        ?>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need javascript if you want it to do things without refreshing the page. PHP is server side only, by the time it hits your browser the php process has already died

Comment: Well thankyou that you pointed out about javascript but i need example code or something that i could acctually use in my code because i'm having trouble finding something similar what i need.

Comment: Why can't you just have one submit button, and grab all values on post?

Comment: Because this is just simplyfied code of my real work with mysqli querys and etc, i just need to functionallity to work like this. I don't mind reworking whole code but i don't know how, i'm beginner.

Comment: delete the first submit, and just submit both values using the second button

Comment: Look man, this is just simplified code, i need function to work with 2 buttons, i don't really need to combine first and second  values... The idea is that you can't see second select before selecting first.

Comment: Ah! In that case, why not only display the first select if `$_POST['Color']` has NOT been set. If it HAS been set, create an input of type hidden called Color and put the value in that. It will be submitted with the second value.

Comment: And what if i make mysql SELECT when i press the first button to fill second select and every 1st select makes 2nd select different and after that i want to INSERT the choice of user into my database? how can i select and insert with same button?

Comment: You can't do this in PHP without the PHP being able to "remember" previous selections from earlier invocations of the form. This is possible by using $_SESSION variables (or several other more involved methods) to save "state". You need to read up on this and try it out. Otherwise make a HTML form and use Javascript variables to save state or make AJAX calls to update the form depending on previous selections. If you don't succeed I will look to a solution for you but tomorrow AM Australia time.